After upgrade 22.04 to 24.04, start delays by 2 minutes on udev, udev-problems?
After the release upgrade 22.04 to 24.04, the start is delayed by about two minutes due to some udev problem. One can see it here, between 14:27:28 and 14:29:19, when nothing happens until udev times out (journalctl):
Aug 31 14:27:28 My-ThinkPad-Helix-2nd systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 31 14:27:49 My-ThinkPad-Helix-2nd systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 31 14:28:23 My-ThinkPad-Helix-2nd systemd-udevd[570]: bdw_rt286: Worker [618] processing SEQNUM=4265 is taking a long time
Aug 31 14:28:23 My-ThinkPad-Helix-2nd systemd-udevd[570]: 2-002c: Worker [617] processing SEQNUM=4534 is taking a long time
Aug 31 14:29:19 My-ThinkPad-Helix-2nd udevadm[593]: Timed out for waiting the udev queue being empty.
Aug 31 14:29:19 My-ThinkPad-Helix-2nd systemd[1]: systemd-udev-settle.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 31 14:29:19 My-ThinkPad-Helix-2nd systemd[1]: systemd-udev-settle.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 31 14:29:19 My-ThinkPad-Helix-2nd systemd[1]: Failed to start systemd-udev-settle.service - Wait for udev To Complete Device Initialization.
Aug 31 14:29:19 My-ThinkPad-Helix-2nd systemd[1]: Reached target sysinit.target - System Initialization.

This has never happend earlier. It popped up immediately and reproducible with 24.04.1 after the release upgrade. I had filed it as bug, under #2078564. However, it was thrown out as 'invalid', and I was told to ask here, how to solve it.
This udev problem might have to make with the impossible auto-mount of external drives at startup, also posed as question here.

Did you find an answer?

No. I have more than one lenovo thinkpads Heliox 2, tried the second, and it fails likewise completely after that upgrade.

It's a common problem - search 'timed out waiting for the udev queue being empty'. I haven't got a fix yet. Booting with NOMODESET doesn't help. 24.04.1 seems to have poor graphics support, among other issues.

24.04.1 is poor in many aspects ... Thanks for your advice! But I have already uninstalled it; and - after more than 25 years - ponder to go back to Windoze. Just installed W10 on my main machine.
Can you imagine, that it doesn't shut down properly, it hangs after the poweroff; and then it doesn't boot up again. It takes me up to 10 minutes to get it to power on again. No, the machine is okay, W10 shuts down and powers on without any hitch.
